# A foreign key field is not rendered inside an inline model admin in django

Tags: django, django-admin, django-modeladmin

I'm creating a small site to register sporting event results. I have two following models:

- Team
- Player (of a team)
- Match
- Goals (scored by a Player on a Match)

in more detail:

```
class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Player(models.Model):
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    total_goals = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"%s (%s)" % (self.name, self.team)


class Match(TimeStampedModel):
    competition = models.ForeignKey(Competition)
    league = models.ForeignKey(League, null=True, blank=True)  # null==True, ha osztalyozo

    home = models.ForeignKey(Team, related_name="merkozes_home")
    away = models.ForeignKey(Team, related_name="merkozes_away")
    home_score = models.SmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    away_score = models.SmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    goal_list = models.ManyToManyField(Player, through='Goal')

    @property
    def winner(self):
        return self.home if self.home_score > self.away_score else self.away

    @property
    def loser(self):
        return self.home if self.home_score < self.away_score else self.away

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('league', 'home', 'away'),)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"%s - %s (%s)" % (self.home, self.away, self.competition)


class Goal(TimeStampedModel):
    player = models.ForeignKey(Player)
    ,atch = models.ForeignKey(Match)
    goals = models.SmallIntegerField(default=0)
    self_goal = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True)
```

I would like to edit goals together with match details under the django admin. Thus I've created the following admin models:

```
class GoalsInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Goal
    extra = 1

@admin.register(Match)
class MerkozesAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [GoalsInline]
```

Strangely, my admin inline does not show the `player` fields, just the other fields from the `Goal` model. I checked the html code too, and it's not even a hidden field.

Do you have any idea what might be the reason for this and how can I get all the fields be shown?

Answer (score 1):

Your `GoalsInline` will only show a select field for the `Player` object because it is a ForeignKey.

One alternative is register the `Player` class in the admin for the plus sign to show up in the inline so you can add a new `Player` object from that inline.

```
@admin.register(Player)
class PlayerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass
```

[image: From Admin]